# Retina 2012 15" Macbook Pro: Vertical Lines like dead pixels

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I recently purchased a used MacBook Pro 15" Retina (2012). Before I bought it, its screen was replaced entirely and so was its upper case. I am currently using Windows 10 on the laptop.

I started noticing intermittent vertical lines 1 pixel wide when using the machine. At first I thought it was a row of dead pixels, but the screen will sometimes go back to working properly for no reason what so ever. Sometimes the lines are a bright magenta or dark green. The most persistent line is a very subtle light gray. I take very good care of my electronics and I have never dropped the MacBook. What do you think could be causing this? I believe I am past the previous owner's 90 day warranty on the last repair and the AppleCare expired about a month ago.

Comment: Do these lines appear consistently in the same locations on the screen, or do they appear at random locations on the screen? Do the lines appear only in a particular physical location or locations where you use the laptop, but never in other locations? Perhaps you may be tilting the screen to different angles to avoid light reflections at, for example, Starbucks or at your college study carrel, but you _only_ see the vertical lines when at Starbucks.

Comment: I tried tilting the screen at different angles and the line remains. I also tried toying with the screen brightness settings and covering the ambient light sensor. From what I can tell, one of the lines is now 'permanent' in the sense that it continues to appear in the same spot on the monitor. The other, more vibrant lines, are currently not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Is this only happening when running Windows ? Do you have the same issue when you run MacOS, when your mac boots, or if you are running any other operating system ? It seems like a graphical driver problem. You could maybe try to update your bootcamp drivers if you're using bootcamp. The support of Windows 10 for macbook is very recent so it might be buggy... I had those sorts of problems when running Linux on mac.

Comment: I booted into El Capitan and experienced the same issue. I checked to make sure all my software was up to date as well.